# Reduced induced closed subscheme of finite presentation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\to S$ be a morphism of schemes of finite type, with $X$ irreducible. Assume that $X_{\text{red}}\to S$, where $X_{\text{red}}$ is the reduced induced closed subscheme, is of finite presentation. Is the same true for $X\to S$?